# How to post json to a site from local html form?

Tags: java, html, json, post, http-post

Here is my html:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://backend.hera.potentiaco.com/simavg">
    <textarea name="s" cols="160" rows="40"></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Assume that I have some json data in a file called `data.json`. If I take this json data and paste it in the above html file and click submit, I get some response from the site mentioned by the action tag.

Say I want to do this a 100 times for 100 different json data files. How would I automate this using java? This is what I have tried so far, but I am not getting any output back from the site mentioned by action tag in the above html.

```
String url = "https://backend.hera.potentiaco.com/simavg";

// Assume that I have the data in json variable after this next line
String json = readFile(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
StringEntity jsonEntity = new StringEntity(json, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
post.setEntity(jsonEntity);
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);

String jsonNew = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(jsonNew);
```

**Expected input and output:**

Say I have some random json data like `sdfg` and if I paste this manually in my html form and click submit, I get an output as :

```
{
    "error": "illegal value"
}
```

But I am unable to get the same output using the above java code. So how should I post the data properly? I see that my url is the site's address itself. How should I use my html file in my java code?

Comment: Do you need to do this in code? There are some tools for that, to post data to url's?

Comment: But isn't that what many programs in java do? I mean all that json parsing and get/post things are very famous in java right? I mean that's what these things are written for right?

Comment: Yes of course you can do these programmatically, but if you need to post these data for testing purposes or such, you can use applications, like Postman, define your data and send it to your url. These applications save you from losing time. But if you really need to do this in code, let me check.

Comment: Yes I need to do it in java, because I later on need to run some machine learning algorithms on this data and get the results back from the site. I remember learning about servlet's etc in school, but I've never used anything like get or post extensively.

Comment: Any updates? @M.OğuzÖzcan